# Speech recognition from console to forms c#

Tags: c#

Okay, so I was basically working on a program in the console application format. After discovering that a push-to-talk key would be pretty much impossible to create in console application, I proceed to revamp the project and do it instead in windows forms.

In my console application project the speech recognition works great, it takes all my commands and output whatever I have set it do to. However, when I copy the code over to forms and launch it, with some few modifications it launches but whenever I say the commands nothing happens. I really need help with this now as I am stuck and have no clue why in my windows form project its not working.

(working code) Console application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        public static bool keyHold = false;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
            {
                Console.Write("Commands: ");
                string[] commands2 = new string[] { "Dollar", "Euro", "Hotmail", "Notepad", "Outlook", "Onedrive", "Discord" };
                for (int i = 1; i < commands2.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(commands2[i] + " | ");
                }

                recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognized);

                Choices commands = new Choices();
                commands.Add(new string[] { "dollar", "euro", "hotmail", "notepad", "outlook", "onedrive", "discord" });
                GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
                gBuilder.Append(commands);
                Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

                recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
                recEngine.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                Console.ReadKey();
                recEngine.SpeechRecognized -= recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }

        internal static void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {

                switch (e.Result.Text)
                {
                    //case "dollar":
                    //    Console.WriteLine("10kr");
                    //    break;

                    //case "euro":
                    //    Console.WriteLine("A lot more");
                    //    break;

                    case "notepad":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                        break;

                    case "hotmail":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://outlook.live.com/owa/");
                        break;

                    case "outlook":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://outlook.live.com/owa/");
                        break;

                    case "ondrive":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://onedrive.live.com/");
                        break;

                    case "discord":
                        string name = Environment.UserName;
                        string path = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.300\Discord.exe", name);
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
                        break;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

(need help with this one compared to the other link above) Windows forms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SpeechRecognitionForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine; 
        public static bool keyHold = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())

            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognized);
            //recEngine.AudioStateChanged += new EventHandler<AudioStateChangedEventArgs>(recEngine_AudioStateChange);
            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "dollar", "euro", "hotmail", "notepad", "outlook", "onedrive", "discord" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(commands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
            recEngine.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            recEngine.SpeechRecognized -= recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
            //recEngine.AudioStateChanged -= recEngine_AudioStateChange;
        }

        //internal void recEngine_AudioStateChange(object sender, AudioStateChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    textBox1.Text = string.Format("Audio state: {0}", e.AudioState);
        //}

        internal static void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch(e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "notepad":
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                    break;

                case "hotmail":
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://outlook.live.com/owa/");
                    break;

                case "outlook":
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://outlook.live.com/owa/");
                    break;

                case "ondrive":
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://onedrive.live.com/");
                    break;

                case "discord":
                    string name = Environment.UserName;
                    string path = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.300\Discord.exe", name);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You create and dispose of he speech recognition instance in FormLoad. Indeed reliably disposing of it is literally the job of the using clause. Going from Console to WinForms is not a easy change. You move from a purely procedural approach to Event driven one. And worst of all, you have to keep a Disposeable resource around during runtime (the SpeechRecognitionEngine instance). I do not envy you that problem. At least when I worked with speech recognition, I got to limit it to a webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make speech recognition a public variable of the class:

public SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine; //= new SpeechRecognitionEngine())

Instantiate it in the form load:

```
recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
```

include all the other code there, except this (it's removing events):

```
recEngine.SpeechRecognized -= recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
recEngine.AudioStateChanged -= recEngine_AudioStateChange;
```

Then, in your form dispose method, dispose of recEngine there.  You'll find it in the FormName.designer.cs file where FormName is the name of your form.

```
recEngine.Dispose();
```

If there isn't a Dispose method, you'll have to create one at the form level.

Here's a sample of what it might look like in the Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine;
    public static bool keyHold = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate the Recognition At Class Level
        recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        // Add Events
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognized);
        recEngine.AudioStateChanged += new EventHandler<AudioStateChangedEventArgs>(recEngine_AudioStateChange);
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "dollar", "euro", "hotmail", "notepad", "outlook", "onedrive", "discord" });
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
        recEngine.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        //recEngine.SpeechRecognized -= recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
        //recEngine.AudioStateChanged -= recEngine_AudioStateChange;
    }

    internal void recEngine_AudioStateChange(object sender, AudioStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("Audio state: {0}", e.AudioState);
    }

    internal static void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "notepad":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                break;

            case "hotmail":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://outlook.live.com/owa/");
                break;

            case "outlook":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://outlook.live.com/owa/");
                break;

            case "ondrive":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://onedrive.live.com/");
                break;

            case "discord":
                string name = Environment.UserName;
                string path = string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.300\Discord.exe", name);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

and make sure in the form1.designer.cs, the Dispose method has the recEngine dispose added.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            try { this.recEngine.Dispose(); } catch (System.Exception ex) { } // Cleanup, We Don't Need to Handle Error

            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply!, So i undid this line "public SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();" to just "public SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine;". and in the Form1_load scope i declared "recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();" above the "using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())" . This is my current code so far and still not working. I can not move the recEngine_SpeechRecognized event handler inside the form1_load scope , if i do so it just causes alot of error. this is my current code of the whole project

Comment: This is where i added the recEngine.Dispose(); method. I have no clue if this is correct . https://gyazo.com/ff892e4a2e9b0911021fa27a6bdc8819 (line 19)

Comment: the using statement needs to be abandoned...it should be a public variable now at the class level...instantiated in the form...and disposed of in the form's dispose method...that probably explains the problems with your most recent update

Comment: Hey, okay so i updated my question with the current code pastebin!

Comment: I removed the using statement but it still doesnt register my commands :/

Comment: i don't have access to paste bin...you can maybe include the entire classes code above?

Comment: try what's above...ive integrated my changes into your form

Comment: just made another update...form load wasnt getting called...pretty important

Comment: Oh wow okey i see, so you basicly removed the " -= " events and added "this.load += form1_load"under initialize components! I will check whenever i get home    ty for help so far ^^

Comment: Form oad function cannot do anything if it's not called....and the -= removes events...no need for that in this context...good luck

Comment: Hey! okay so it is now working! i had to remove the "this.load += form1_load" as it makes the program open each command twice for some reason. I removed it and now it only open once.

Comment: Means it was calling load event elsewhere...if u like...can u please accept answer?...glad to hear it

Comment: I think i did it now, Like first time i use this forum so :)